# flatlist of pictures is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render a flatlist of images in a child component. The array of pictures is part of the parent state component and contains the uri for each picture. I am passing it like this to the child:

```
<ImagePickerAndList
  pictures={this.state.pictures}
/>
```

And then the flatList in `<ImagePickerAndList />`

```
<FlatList //what I see is nothing renders
  data={props.pictures}
  extraData={props.pictures}
  horizontal
  keyExtractor={picture => picture} //no idea if this is a good practice or not
  renderItem={({ picture }) => {
     console.log(picture); //this will log undefined for each item in list
     console.log('hi'); //this will log for each item in list
     return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
           <Image source={{ uri: picture }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
        </View>
     );
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the variable name inside the renderitem.
If you want to iterate over the array then for each element you have to use item and the index just use index.

Now just edit your code and it will works

```
<FlatList //what I see is nothing renders
  data={props.pictures}
  extraData={props.pictures}
  horizontal
  keyExtractor={picture => picture} //no idea if this is a good practice or not
  renderItem={({ item,index }) => {
     console.log(picture); //this will log undefined for each item in list
     console.log('hi'); //this will log for each item in list
     return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
           <Image source={{ uri: item}} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
        </View>
     );
  }}
/>
```

> item - > getting elements from the array
>
> index -> index of the current element

I hope it helps thanks :)

Comment: yeah, funny thing is if you use other names then it will not work....only item and index :),,,,Accept it if it works thanks @goolius_boozler

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the variable name inside the renderitem. If you want to iterate over the array then for each element you have to use item and the index just use index.

Now just edit your code and it will works

```
<FlatList //what I see is nothing renders
   data={props.pictures}
   extraData={props.pictures}
   horizontal
   keyExtractor={picture => picture} //no idea if this is a good practice or not
   renderItem={({ item,index }) => {
   console.log(picture); //this will log undefined for each item in list
   console.log('hi'); //this will log for each item in list
   return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Image source={{ uri: item}} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
      </View>
   );
  }}
/>
```